# Text Shift function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing code so you can shift text two places along the alphabet: 'ab cd' should become 'cd ef'. I'm using Python 2 and this is what I got so far:

```
def shifttext(shift):
    input=raw_input('Input text here: ')
    data = list(input)
    for i in data:
        data[i] = chr((ord(i) + shift) % 26)
        output = ''.join(data)
    return output
shifttext(3)
```

I get the following error:

```
File "level1.py", line 9, in <module>
    shifttext(3)
File "level1.py", line 5, in shifttext
    data[i] = chr((ord(i) + shift) % 26)
TypError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

So I have to change the letter to numbers somehow? But I thought I already did that?

Comment: You  forgot to call the function I guess, try : `shifttext(3)`.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `return` with `print`?

Comment: If I print, I get nothing again, If I actually call it (good point!) I get an error, I'll add it to the question, thanks!

Comment: Also, `ord('a')` is 97, so `% 26` will produce unwanted results. You also don't need to reassign `output` in the for loop. The traceback is because of `data[i]` - maybe you want `for i, el in enumerate(data): data[i]...` where `el` is the actual letter and `i` is the index

Comment: I guess using maketrans would be easier, because punctuation would stil be existing.

Comment: Hey is this question for pythonchallenge.com level 2?  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks you're doing cesar-cipher encryption, so you can try something like this:

```
strs = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'      # use a string like this, instead of ord() 
def shifttext(shift):
    inp = raw_input('Input text here: ')
    data = []
    for i in inp:                     # iterate over the text not some list
        if i.strip() and i in strs:                 # if the char is not a space ""  
            data.append(strs[(strs.index(i) + shift) % 26])    
        else:
            data.append(i)           # if space then simply append it to data
    output = ''.join(data)
    return output
```

**output:**

```
In [2]: shifttext(3)
Input text here: how are you?
Out[2]: 'krz duh brx?'

In [3]: shifttext(3)
Input text here: Fine.
Out[3]: 'Flqh.'
```

`strs[(strs.index(i) + shift) % 26]`:  line above means find the index of the character `i` in `strs` and then add the shift value to it.Now, on the final value(index+shift) apply %26 to the get the shifted index. This shifted index when passed to `strs[new_index]`  yields the desired shifted character.

Comment: @AmpiSevere what was your input?

Comment: A shifted (ununderstandble) piece of text consisting of words, spaces and ending with a period and one apostroph in there by the way.

Comment: @AmpiSevere I've fixed the code to handle such characters(i.e .,;") as well.

Comment: Okay, no error but now I get no return, and after the function definition I actually call it. I've had this issue almost on everything, I don't understand where it comes from.

Comment: @AmpiSevere try calling the function like this:
`print shifttext(3)`

Comment: Perfect, but it doesn't work with longer pieces of text: IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: My entire input needs to be: "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj." Which I almost have.

Comment: @AmpiSevere for that input at shift=2, I get : **i hope you didnt translate it by hand. thats what computers are for. doing it in by hand is inefficient and that's why this text is so long. using string.maketrans() is recommended. now apply on the url.** this as the output.

Comment: Got it! Forgot a letter in my alphabet :-)

Answer (score 11):

You are looping over the list of characters, and `i` is thus a character. You then try to store that back into `data` using the `i` character as an index. That won't work.

Use `enumerate()` to get indexes *and* the values:

```
def shifttext(shift):
    input=raw_input('Input text here: ')
    data = list(input)
    for i, char in enumerate(data):
        data[i] = chr((ord(char) + shift) % 26)
    output = ''.join(data)
    return output
```

You can simplify this with a generator expression:

```
def shifttext(shift):
    input=raw_input('Input text here: ')
    return ''.join(chr((ord(char) + shift) % 26) for char in input)
```

But now you'll note that your `% 26` won't work; the ASCII codepoints *start* after 26:

```
>>> ord('a')
97
```

You'll need to use the `ord('a')` value to be able to use a modulus instead; subtracting puts your values in the range 0-25, and you add it again afterwards:

```
    a = ord('a')
    return ''.join(chr((ord(char) - a + shift) % 26) + a) for char in input)
```

but that will only work for lower-case letters; which might be fine, but you can force that by lowercasing the input:

```
    a = ord('a')
    return ''.join(chr((ord(char) - a + shift) % 26 + a) for char in input.lower())
```

If we then move asking for the input out of the function to focus it on doing one job well, this becomes:

```
def shifttext(text, shift):
    a = ord('a')
    return ''.join(chr((ord(char) - a + shift) % 26 + a) for char in text.lower())

print shifttext(raw_input('Input text here: '), 3)
```

and using this on the interactive prompt I see:

```
>>> print shifttext(raw_input('Input text here: '), 3)
Input text here: Cesarsalad!
fhvduvdodgr
```

Of course, now punctuation is taken along. Last revision, now only shifting letters:

```
def shifttext(text, shift):
    a = ord('a')
    return ''.join(
        chr((ord(char) - a + shift) % 26 + a) if 'a' <= char <= 'z' else char
        for char in text.lower())
```

and we get:

```
>>> print shifttext(raw_input('Input text here: '), 3)
Input text here: Ceasarsalad!
fhdvduvdodg!
```

Comment: `ord('a')` is 97, so the `% 26` will produce still random characters

Comment: Okay, error has gone, but I get no return. If I change to print I get 3 empty lines.

Comment: Yes! Now I get it working, thanks for the step by step build up! :-)

Comment: `output = ''.join(data)` shouldn't be in the for loop

Comment: Anyway this code could keep punctuation? Now I get this " character in various places when inputting a larger piece of text.

Comment: @AmpiSevere: You'd have to detect what characters you wanted to convert; test for the range `'a' <= char <= 'z'`; added that for you.

Comment: Great job. Saved me having to write this from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Martijn's answer is great. Here is another way to achieve the same thing:

```
import string

def shifttext(text, shift):
    shift %= 26 # optional, allows for |shift| > 26 
    alphabet = string.lowercase # 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' (note: for Python 3, use string.ascii_lowercase instead)
    shifted_alphabet = alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift]
    return string.translate(text, string.maketrans(alphabet, shifted_alphabet))

print shifttext(raw_input('Input text here: '), 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to write a straight function `shifttext(text, shift)`. If you want a prompt, use Python's interactive mode `python -i shift.py`

```
> shifttext('hello', 2)
'jgnnq'
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried with Basic python.
may useful for someone.

```
# Caesar cipher
import sys

text = input("Enter your message: ")

cipher = ''
try:
  number = int(input("Enter Number to shift the value : "))
except ValueError:
  print("Entered number should be integer. please re0enter the value")
  try:
    number = int(input("Enter Number to shift the value : "))
  except:
    print("Error occurred. please try again.")
    sys.exit(2)
  
for char in text:
    if not char.isalpha():
      flag = char
    elif char.isupper():
      code = ord(char) + number
      if 64 < code <= 90:
        flag = chr(code)
      elif code > 90:
        flag = chr((code - 90) + 64)
        
    elif char.islower():
      code = ord(char) + number
      if 96 < code <= 122:
        flag = chr(code)
      elif code > 122:
        flag = chr((code - 122) + 96)
    
    else:
      print("not supported value by ASCII")
    
    cipher += flag

print(cipher)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works just fine.

```
def rotate(text, key):
result = []

for char in text:
    if char.isalpha():  # Check if the character is alphabetic
        shift = 65 if char.isupper() else 97  # ASCII code for 'A' or 'a'
        new_char = chr((ord(char) - shift + key) % 26 + shift)
    else:
        new_char = char  # Keep non-alphabetic characters unchanged
    result.append(new_char)

return ''.join(result)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).