# Get the indices of capital letters in a string

Tags: python, string

Say for example I have the following string:

```
Hello
```

And my job is to shift all the letters over by however many spots I am told to, and lets say it is 1, so the result would be:

```
elloH
```

But my program returns it as

```
elloh
```

What I want to know is, how can I get a list with the indices of where a capital letter is, so I can make the letters at that same spot in the new string uppercase?

I think you would do it by converting the String to a list through `list(string)` and then iterate through the list so, and whenever the item in the list returns `true` for `isUpper()`, then  store the index of that in a list. I just am not able to write it in python.

Comment: Can you add the code you use to do this currently?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i check if a letter in a string is capialized using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697535/how-can-i-check-if-a-letter-in-a-string-is-capialized-using-python)

Comment: @paisanco no its not a duplicate. I already wrote in my question if you read it that I do know how to check with isUpper()

Comment: @mu無 the code I am using is from Ashwini's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424500/text-shift-function-in-python), just slightly modified for a different task

Comment: Go ahead and paste it in. It'll make this question easier to answer.

Comment: Nothing to do with regular expressions, so I removed the tag. However, your question is not specific enough for the solution you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will assume that your question is regarding:

> And my job is to shift all the letters over by however many spots I am told to

In that case, try:

```
def shift(s, n): 
    return s[n:] + s[:n]
```

Examples:

```
>>> shift('Hello', 1)
'elloH'
>>> shift('Hello', 2)
'lloHe'
```

This appears to be the output that you were looking for.

#### How to get indices of the capital letters in a string:

```
def getindices(s):
    return [i for i, c in enumerate(s) if c.isupper()]
```

Examples:

```
>>> getindices('Hello')
[0]
>>> getindices('HeLlO')
[0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: That fits my purpose for this problem I have, but doesn't answer the question I have (Get the indices of capital letters in a string), so I'll +1 this, but won't accept yet.

Comment: @CyanogenCX don't you think the best answer is to eliminate the problem completely before it even comes up? This answer does that. I'm having trouble conceiving how you got your original result, since you didn't share any code.

Comment: @CyanogenCX OK.  I added a solution for getting indices of capital letters.

Comment: @MarkRansom No, I think the best answer is one that answers the question I asked. Which John has done now. I just put the background about my current problem to give some context, but the goal of this question was not to solve the problem, but to find the answer to the question I asked in the title.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the solution by @John1024

This supports *any* number to rotate by

```
def shift(s, n):
    return s[n%len(s):] + text[:n%len(s)]
```

---

```
>>> shift('Hello', 51)
'elloH'
```