# Getting indices of capital letters with regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to get the indices of capital letters (including special ones) in a line. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402480/get-the-indices-of-capital-letters-in-a-string) the following solution:

```
[i for i, c in enumerate(s) if c.isupper()]
```

However, this does not work for letters like: `Ö, Ä` and `Ü`: 
[image]

I tried therefore:

```
[re.search(r'^([^A-ZÄÖÜ]*[A-ZÄÖÜ]){i}',s).span()[1] for i in range (1,y)]
```

where y is the number of capital letters in `s`.

The second solution works if I define `i`, but under the loop, it returns:

> attributeerror 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'span'.

How can I solve it in an efficient way?

Comment: `s = "ÖÄÜ"; [i for i, c in enumerate(s) if c.isupper()]` works fine and returns `[0, 1, 2]` on my computer.

Comment: I added a figure, showing that it does not work for me :)

Comment: Interesting. I tested it on Python 2.7 and Python 3.6, it works fine on 3.6 but fails with 2.7. Are you using Python 2.7? Do you have the option to update to Python 3?

Comment: I actually found the solution. Just the UNICODE. s=u'ÖÄÜ' solves the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense now.

Comment: @DYEZ: As you have found the solution, you can post it as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `s` is represented in bytes. It needs just to be decoded to unicode:

```
s=u'ÖÄÜ'       # str to unicode
[i for i, c in enumerate(s) if c.isupper()]
```

Answer (score -1):

Python3: You can do that with `isupper()` easily, no need for regex. Unfortunately, if you are using Python2.7 this will involve some nasty encoding/decoding, which I am not so familiar with.

```
x = "HEY thats Some Lower Case ZÄÖÜ"
print([i for i in range(0, len(x)) if x[i].isupper() ])
>[0, 1, 2, 10, 15, 21, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

Comment: My question is about special characters

Comment: Special Characters or `vowel characters` like the `german Umlaut` If yes, this one works with `ä, Ä, ö, Ö, ü, Ü`as well. Oh...i am on python3 that might b the difference lemme check.