# How to shift characters according to ascii order using Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, character, ascii

For example, `hello, world` should be converted to `ifmmo, xpsme`. (`a` -> `b`, `b` -> `c`, ..., `z` -> `a`)

In C, one can simply write `print ch+1;` to do the shifting. However, when trying to do this Python, I get:

```
>>> [i+1 for i in "hello, world"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424500/text-shift-function-in-python) question has a reply that works for your problem.

Comment: @Maurice Indeed. What should I do now? Delete this post, cast a close vote(which I've already done) or write answer?

Answer (score 3):

check out this

```
a = [chr(ord(i)+1) for i in "hello, world"]
print ''.join(map(str,a))
```

or

```
for i in "hello, world":
    if i.isalpha():
        b.append(chr(ord(i)+1))
    elif i == ' ' or i == ',':
        b.append(i)
print ''.join(map(str,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the functions to shift characters in string. I am also changing the logic in both functions for better clarity.

- Using *list comprehension*:

  ```
  import string
  alph_string = string.ascii_letters # string of both uppercase/lowercase letters

  def shift_string(my_string, shift):
       return ''.join([chr(ord(c)+shift) if c in alph_string else c for c in my_string])
  ```
- Using *custom function* (with plain logic):

  ```
  import string
  my_alphas = string.ascii_lowercase  # string of lowercase alphabates 

  def shift_string(my_string, shift):
      new_string = ''
      for i in my_string:
          if i in my_alphas:
              pos = my_alphas.index(i) + shift
              if pos >  len(my_alphas):
                  pos -= len(my_alphas)
              new_string += my_alphas[pos]
          else:
              new_string += i
      return new_string
  ```

Sample run:

```
# with shift 1
>>> shift_string(my_string, 1)
'ifmmp, xpsme'

# with shift 2
>>> shift_string(my_string, 2)
'jgnnq, yqtnf'
```